# Migrating schema, table, data, function, stored procedure from MS SQL to Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Is there any open source tool available to migrate schema, tables, data, function, stored procedure from MS SQL to PostgreSQL?

Comment: You have asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002759/migrating-schema-table-data-function-stored-procedure-from-ms-sql-to-postgre) again. Read [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Microsoft_SQL_Server) wiki

Comment: http://dalibo.github.io/sqlserver2pgsql/

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called full convert using which you can migrate across different databases.
You need to take the dump from MS SQL and then you can migrate it to psql.